# Run tensorflow on gpu

Tags: linux, tensorflow, gpu, centos7

This is my GPU info:

```
[root@happy mytflayer]# lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350] (rev 87)
```

I just installed `tensorflow` on CentOS7. How can I run it on GPU?

Comment: To run tensorflow on GPU your videocard should be CUDA compatible. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

AMD cards don't do tensorflow, or machine learning in general. Caffe has some OpenCL support, but everyone I talked to said it was really slow